# Warning in Linked Lists- assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, compiler-warnings

I am trying to write program which takes in song names, genres, and artists.
The code to input these is this:

```
printf("Genre: ");
getStringFromUserInput(input, MAX_LENGTH);
length = strlen(input);
genre = (char*)malloc(length);
strcpy(genre, input);
getStringFromUserInput(input, MAX_LENGTH);
```

I have a function to initialize a new node, but when building the program it is giving me the warning.

```
Node *newNode(char songName, char artist, char genre, Node *link){
    Node *new;
    new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); //dynamic memory allocation of 1 node
    if(new!=NULL){
        //if there is memory, inputs data into bucket
        new->songName = songName;
        new->artist = artist;
        new->genre = genre;
        new->link = link;
    }
    return (new);
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: [Don't cast malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `char songName` means the song's name is just one character. Don't you mean `char *songName` and the same for `artist` and `genre`?

Comment: yes Thank you! not sure how I missed that.

Comment: `length = strlen(input); genre = malloc(length); strcpy(genre, input);` You're copying one more character than you allocated.  Don't forget the terminating `'\0'`.